# Configure keycloak.service to run keycloak 18.0.2 as a daemon process in rhel

Tags: keycloak, daemon, rhel

I try to configure keycloak.service in systemd to run keycloak 18.0.2 as a daemon process. There is current folder which symlink to kk folder. I try to start kk in dev mode on port 8180

```
[Unit]
Description=Keycloak
After=network.target
 
[Service]
Type=idle
User=keycloak
Group=keycloak
ExecStart=/opt/keycloak/current/bin/kc.sh start-dev --http-port=8180 
TimeoutStartSec=600
TimeoutStopSec=600
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it didn't work.
Also if i just run

```
bin/kc.sh start-dev --http-port=8180
```

it work correctly, but not as a daemon process

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem. Right configuration is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Keycloak
After=network.target
 
[Service]
User=keycloak
Group=keycloak
ExecStart=/opt/keycloak/current/bin/kc.sh start-dev --http-port=8180 

 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Make sure that correct user have all needded rights

```
chown keycloak: -R /opt/keycloak
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to configure systemd service to use `Type=notify` rather than the default `Type=simple`.

Using `Type=simple`, the service manager (systemd) will consider the service started immediately after the service process has been forked off, even if it fails to start correctly. While using `Type=notify`, the service manager will wait for a signal notification by the service process to consider it as started.

You can achieve that by using this quarkiverse extension:

- https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-systemd-notify

---

#### Steps to configure Keycloak systemd service:

Assuming Keycloak distribution is located at `/opt/keycloak`:

1. Add the following jar files to `/opt/keycloak/providers` directory:

- [quarkus-systemd-notify-deployment-1.0.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkiverse/systemd/notify/quarkus-systemd-notify-deployment/1.0.2/quarkus-systemd-notify-deployment-1.0.2.jar)
- [quarkus-systemd-notify-1.0.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkiverse/systemd/notify/quarkus-systemd-notify/1.0.2/quarkus-systemd-notify-1.0.2.jar)

2. Create a unit configuration file at `/etc/systemd/system/keycloak.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Keycloak Server
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_ADMIN
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/opt/jre
ExecStart=/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev --http-port=8080 --log=console,file --log-file=/var/log/keycloak/keycloak.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Enable the service (this will make it to run at system start-up as well):

```
sudo systemctl enable keycloak
```

4. Start/Stop/Restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl start keycloak
sudo systemctl stop keycloak
sudo systemctl restart keycloak
```

5. Check status of the service:

```
sudo systemctl status keycloak
```

Comment: (1) You can't use type `simple` for services that fork, and (2) `systemd` will correctly report failure for type `simple` services that fail to start. `notify` *may* be a better option for Keycloak, but *only* if Keycloak actually needs to communicate some status back to systemd, *and* `kc.sh` actually uses `systemd-notify`.  AFAIK, kc.sh is not systemd-aware, so using `notify` is just busywork.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **!** before the commnd and it will work like that :

```
ExecStart=!/opt/keycloak/current/bin/kc.sh start-dev --http-port=8180
```

Comment: dont forget tu give rigth permission :
groupadd keycloak
useradd -r -g keycloak -d /opt/keycloak -s /sbin/nologin keycloak
## Keycloak permissions
chown -R keycloak:keycloak /opt/keycloak
chmod -R o+rwx /opt/keycloak

Answer (score -2):

You are missing the configuraiton file for keycloak to run, another solution would be to directly copy the file at: `~/keycloak/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd/wildfly.service` to your `/etc/systemd/system/` repertory, either way your deamon file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Keycloak Server
After=network.target


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/keycloak/keycloak.conf
User=keycloak
Group=keycloak
PIDFile=/var/run/keycloak/keycloak.pid
ExecStart=/opt/keycloak/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: But there is no launch.sh in kk 18, only kc.sh. Is it same?

Comment: yes it is, but dont forget the keycloak conf file that containes DB name, hostname...