# How to set a startscript in Linux for Keycloak Quarkus up to Version 17 , 18 or 19 in systemctl

Tags: linux, keycloak

How to set a startscript in Linux for Keycloak Quarkus up to Version 17 , 18 or 19, in order to run KeyCloak as a daemon. Actually I am not searching for a KeyCloak Wildfly solution!

I allready found this solution:

```
./kc.sh start-dev > keycloak.stdout 2>&1 & echo "$!" > keycloak.pid
```

for starting KeyCloak with a PID

How can I build a startscript in systemctl format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is an alternative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75991067/597657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following configuration did the trick for me.

1.) Configure keycloak using database: mysql first

```
kc.sh build --db mysql
```

2.) Insert environment variables to the corresponding keycloak user on your system

```
KEYCLOAK_HOME=/opt/keycloak
export PATH=$PATH:$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin
```

3.) Create a systemd start-stop-script in: /usr/lib/systemd/system named: keycloak.service for example.

```
[Unit]
Description=keycloak service
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start
PIDFile=/var/run/keycloak.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

ExecStart defines your fullpath to the kc.sh script.

Running: systemctl daemon-reload to enable the new startscript

After this you can start/stop keycloak by Quarkus up from version 17 like charme with:

```
systemctl start keycloak
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  thank you for your efforts.